# ¿Como puedo comparar el valor de dos strings para saber si el valor de una es menor que otra?

Tags: java, matrices, ordenamiento, matriz

Estoy intentando entrar en el if despues de comparar si una posición de la matriz con tipo string es menor en valor alfabético que otra como puedo hacer esto, el objetivo es intercambiar las filas si los datos de la columna 0 no estan en orden de mayor a menor.

```
               for (int i = 0; i < datosParticipantes.length; i++) {
                    for (int j = 0; j < datosParticipantes.length - i - 1; j++) {
                        if (datosParticipantes[j][0].compareTo(datosParticipantes[j+1][0])) {
                            // Intercambia 2 filas de la matriz.
                            int[] aux2 = datosParticipantes[j];
                            datosParticipantes[j] = datosParticipantes[j+1];
                            datosParticipantes[j+1] = aux2;
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Comment: que quiere decir "alguien conoce una técnica que sirva sin ser la que uso yo.".. no anda? que problema tiene?

Comment: Cómo ordenar una matriz por filas según el valor de una columna, por que a mi el único algoritmo que me sale es ordenar la matriz entera.

Comment: y si.. se ordena todo.. si no, como la queres ordenar? si ordenas una sola columna, el resto queda cualquier cosa...

Comment: el caso es que datos participates es de tipo string y tengo que compararlos con (< ) menor que, se ejecute el código que esta dentro del bloque del if el caso es como comparar si el datos que esta dentro de x posición es menor que el que esta en x posición no puedo usar el simbolo < uso el metodo compareto pero no lo controlo afu.... , lo que estoy intentando es que en base al resultado del 2020 que pertenece a la columna 0 se ordene las filas de los porticipantes segun su resultado de 2020.

Comment: Quizás [`compareTo`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareTo(java.lang.String)) sea lo que estás buscando.